# Swift UI textfield paste, select all, options appear and then disappear after a second

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

[image]

So this is what I want to happen when a user clicks on the textfield where they are typing. However, in my textfield, code below, this appears for a split seconds and then dissappears. The keyboard also kind of fluctuates when I attempt to bring up the paste option.

```
           TextField("enter url", text: $linkToAdd)
                .keyboardType(.alphabet)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
                .autocorrectionDisabled()
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code. My guess is that something on higher level causes the view to be re-rendered. Try to disable everything else, and see if you can still reproduce it.

Comment: @timbretimbre Thanks. Do you know of anything that could cause the problem at a higher level.

Comment: any change in data / bound variables / state etc can cause parent to re-render, which will cause all the children to rerender too. My suggestion is like I said: strip down your code to just that field and see if it happens. If not, then bring the othercode little by little, and you will se what the issue is